# How to setup email notification for non conformance case and action in SuiteCRM

Tags: suitecrm

I'm setting up to use suitecrm, I've done the email configurations and tried test send email and I've received the email. However when I create a nc action or case then there's no email notification. Where do I go to setup this functionality. The email would have the case number, description, subject and department issued to / raised by.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKAlH.png)

Update

I have created a logic hook but when I enter the data for the nc case instead of it showing the data entered after being save. It gives this error

HTTP 500 error

That's odd... Microsoft Edge can’t find this page

```
class nc_email_notification {
public function email_notification(&$bean, $events, $arguments){

    /*define 'review_pending' as  string constant */

    /*Get sugar email engine*/
    $email = new SugarPHPMailer();
    $email->From = 'suitecrm@gmail.com';
    $email->FromName ='SuiteCRM';

    /*Get the Department NC was Issued to */
    $dept_array= $bean->get_linked_beans('dept_department_nccas_nc_case','dept_Department_sugar');

    if(count($dept_array)==0){      
        /*log error*/
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Could not find the department NC was issued to: ". $bean->name);
    }else{
        /* Get email of users within the Department NC is issued to */              
        $user_array = $dept_array[0]->get_linked_beans('dept_department_users','User');
        if(count($user_array)==0){      
            /*log error*/
            $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Could not find Users within the department NC is issued to: ". $bean->name);
        }else{
            $address=getDepartmentUsersEmail($user_array);
        }


        /*Get the Department NC was raised by */
        $raised_dept_array= $bean->get_linked_beans('dept_department_nccas_nc_case_1','dept_Department_sugar'); 
        if(count($raised_dept_array)==0){       
            /*log error*/
            $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Could not find the department NC was raised by: ". $bean->name);
        }else {
            /*Get email of users within the Department NC is raised by*/
            $raised_user_array = $raised_dept_array[0]->get_linked_beans('dept_department_users','User');
            if(count($raised_user_array)==0){       
                /*log error*/
                $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Could not find Users within the department NC is raised by: ". $bean->name);
            }
            else {
                $r_user_address = getDepartmentUsersEmail($raised_user_array);              
            }
        }


        /*Get the Quality Systems Department*/
        //$qual_dept=$dept_array[0]->retrieve)by)string_fields(array('name' => 'Quality Systems' ));
        //$qual_dept->load_relationship('dept_department_email_addresses_primary');

        /* Send email to Manager */
        $rev_email = 'ramon@gmail.com';


        /*Get NC Action for the NC Case*/
        $action_array = $bean->get_linked_beans('nccas_nc_case_ncact_nc_action','ncact_NC_Action_sugar');

        /* Get sugar template engine */
        $xtpl = new XTemplate("XTemplate/NCEmailTemplate.html");

        /*GEt the URL for the NC Case */
        $url =  $GLOBALS['sugar_config']['site_url'].'index.php?module=ncase_NonConformance&action=DetailView&record='.$bean->id; 
        $xtpl -> assign('URL', $url);

        /* Get NC Status */
        $nc_status=trim($bean->getFieldValue('status'));

        /* Get NC ID */
        $id = $bean->getFieldValue('id');

        if(empty($bean->fetched_row['id'])){

            $email=createNCEmail($email,$rev_email,'New NC Email Notification',$bean,$xtpl);                

            /* Send email to Quality System Manager */
            $email->addaddress($rev_email);

            /* Send email to users of Issued to department  */
            foreach($address as $uemail){                       
                $email->addAddress($uemail);
            }

            }else {
                if (strcasecmp ($nc_status,'review_pending')==0){
                    /* Set Email Subject */
                    $email->Subject = 'NC Case: '. ''. $bean->name . ' '. ' is pending review';

                    /* Send email to users of Raised by department  */
                    foreach($r_user_address as $uemail){                        
                        $email->addAddress($uemail);
                    }
                    /* Send email to Quality System Manager */
                    $email->addaddress($rev_email);


                    /* Create email message using email template */
                    $email=createNCEmailwithAction($email,$action_array,$bean,$xtpl);

                } else if (strcasecmp ($nc_status,'Closed')==0){
                        /* Set Email Subject */
                        $email->Subject = 'NC Case: '. ''. $bean->name . ''. ' is Closed';

                        /* Send email to users of Raised by department  */
                        foreach($r_user_address as $uemail){                        
                            $email->addAddress($uemail);
                        }                       
                        /* Send email to Issued to Department */
                        foreach($address as $iemail){                       
                            $email->addAddress($iemail);
                        }

                        /* Create email message using email template*/
                        $email=createNCEmailwithAction($email,$action_array,$bean,$xtpl);

                } else{

                        If ($bean->fetched_row['description'] != $bean->description){
                        /* Set Email Subject */
                        $email->Subject = 'NC Case: ' .''. $bean->name .''. ' has been modified';

                        /* Create email message using email template */
                        $email=createNCEmailwithAction($email,$action_array,$bean,$xtpl);

                        /* Build appropriate email list */
                        foreach($address as $uemail){                       
                            $email->addAddress($uemail);
                        }
                        /* Send email to Quality System Manager */
                        $email->addaddress($rev_email);

                    }
                }
        }
```

Logic Hook

```
 <?php

$hook_version = 1; 
$hook_array = Array(); 
$hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(1, 'Create NC email object', 'custom/Extension/modules/ncase_NonConformance/Ext/email_notification.php','nc_email_notification', 'email_notification'); 
?>
```

Comment: you will need to check the SuiteCRM log file for any possible issue? if there is any then post it with the question.

Comment: I'm not seeing any possible issue in the log file

Comment: You need to define clear steps that how you create certain records of any module? Also when and to whom you want to trigger email?

Comment: What do you mean to create clear steps? It should be sent to the persons in the department that the issue was raised to

Comment: how that person is selected? have you assigned the issue to him?

Comment: the department is selected from a list of department; so when the issued is raised to that department then the persons in that department should received an email.

Comment: There is no OOTB feature to send email to the user of the specific department. You have to do the customization to get it to work.

Comment: @Star; yeah that's what I realized; I have created a logic hook; but for some reason I think the file is wrong as the module is not being called

Comment: if you have written a logic hook then you need to mention complete details about that in question.

Comment: @Star; I've updated my question

Comment: @Star; is it it possible to give me some assistance I'm not sure why I'm getting that error message

Comment: I don't have exact modules which you are using but at the last you have used  /* Send email to Quality System Manager */
                        $email->addaddress($rev_email);, I think function is addAddress. check if this change fixes an issue for you. Also, check apache and suitecrm log files for possible errors

Comment: I’m not seeing any error in suitecrm log. But I’m wondering is it the file path causing the issue. What does the error message http 500 error means exactly?

Comment: Or if it is not the file path in the logic hook; it could be this line $url =  $GLOBALS['sugar_config']['site_url'].'index.php?module=ncase_NonConformance&action=DetailView&record='.$bean->id; because the nc case is save it only gives this url http://ip_addrss/suitecrm/index.php

Comment: 500 internal server error is a really basic thing in php. google it that how you can resolve it, also check server error log files.

Comment: @Star; I made the change but I'm still getting the error message and I've google it but haven't found any way to resolve it

Comment: @Star; when I remove the logic hook then save works ok but when I add the logic hook I get the http 500 error

Comment: Server Error I'm seeing but I don't understand it  Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.38.0, time stamp: 0x5c4466a6
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7ba58
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000ce653
Faulting process id: 0x1a1c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4efec78285bdb
Faulting application path: E:\Bitnami\SUITEC~1.2-0\apache2\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
Report Id: a2786924-5d2d-11e9-bf18-00155d05c524

Comment: @Star; I've figured out the error message but my next issue is here 
    if(count($dept_array)==0){      
        /*log error*/
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Could not find the department NC was issued to: ". $bean->name);
    } it is throwing the error in the log file.

Comment: What error it is throwing?

Comment: This error message Could not find Users within the department NC is issued to

Comment: Simple, count($dept_array) is returning 0 so it is executing that block of the code. So just make sure that count($dept_array) greater than 0 value.

Comment: Yeah I realized but still not getting why. I'm wondering if it the relationship causing it; although the relationship table would be empty